# How to count occurance of foreign key in multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables:

`Table_one` has row `id` and `text`
other tables have foreign keys `table_one_id`
I want to count how many times the foreign key occurs in different table separately.

Table one looks like this

```
id text
1  tx
2  tx
3  tx
```

table two looks like this:

```
id text table_one_id_fk
 1   tx      1
 2   tx      2
 3   tx      2
 4   tx      1
 5   tx      3
 6   tx      2
 7   tx      2
```

Table three looks like this:

```
id text table_one_id_fk
 1   tx      1
 2   tx      3
 3   tx      2
 4   tx      1
 5   tx      1
 6   tx      3
```

I want to get table like this:

```
id  text  table_two_count table_three_count
1   txt        2                 3
2   txt        4                 1
3   txt        1                 2
```

I run query like this:

```
SELECT table_one.id, table_one.text, count(*) 
FROM table_one  
INNER JOIN table_two ON table_two.table_one_id = table_one.id
GROUP BY companies.cin
```

But this give me result only for table_two.

How should the query looks like for the output i want?

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it, you need to left join with both table and count number of matches in each table :

```
SELECT table_one.id, table_one.text
, count(table_two.*) table_two_count
, count(table_three.*) table_three_count
FROM table_one  
LEFT JOIN table_two ON table_two.table_one_id = table_one.id
LEFT JOIN table_three ON table_three.table_one_id = table_one.id
GROUP BY table_one.id, table_one.text
```